# Find possible primes p

Tags: number-theory

Suppose that $p$ is a prime and $n$ is a positive integer, and for every $a$ and $b$ that does not satisfy $a \equiv b \pmod p$, the congruence $-(a^n-b^n)+\binom{n}{1}(a^{n-1}-b^{n-1})+\binom{n}{2}(a^{n-2}-b^{n-2})+...+\binom{n}{n}(a^0-b^0) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ never holds. What are the possible values of $(n,p)$?

I've tried the binomial theorem but it makes stuff so compact and hard to manipulate... other theorems don't really work for all $n$...

Comment: Yeah. The case $n=1$ is true for whatever prime $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints to get you started:

- First simplify the expression in the problem using the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem). Show that the problem can be reformulated as follows: With $f_n(x) = (1+x)^n - 2x^n$ the problem is to find all $(n,p)$ such that
  $$a\not\equiv b\mod p \implies f_n(a) \not\equiv f_n(b) \mod p$$ or in other words find all $(n,p)$ such that  $$\{f_n(0),f_n(1),\ldots,f_n(p-1)\} = \{0,1,2\ldots,p-1\}$$ is a [reduced residue system](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReducedResidueSystem.html) mod $p$.
- Next, I would always start by brute-force testing of the simplest cases $p=2,3,5$ with say $n=1,2,3,4,5$ to get an idea of how to proceed (if you don't already see this). If you do this then a simple pattern of allowed values for $n$ as a function of $p$ will reveal itself. This is what you should try to prove.
- What theorems to use? Note that $f_n$ is a sum of powers which just begs for [Fermats little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem). In order to apply it we should write $n$ in terms of $p-1$. To do this note that we can write a general $n$ on the form $n = i + (p-1)k$ with $0\leq i<p-1$ and $0\leq k$. Insert this into the expression for $f_n$ and apply Fermats theorem.
- Show that $i=1$ is always an allowed value (very easy).
- Finally try to show that other values for $i$ are not allowed (a bit harder).